# Can you recommend a Firefox extension for files download list generation?

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-extensions

I'd like to be able to generate a plain text list of all files of specific types (zips, pdfs, etc.) linked from current displayed page. Can you recommend extension for this other than FlashGot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Link Gopher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7312/), perhaps?

```
Extracts all links from web page, sorts them, removes duplicates, and displays 
them in a new tab for inspection or copy and paste into other systems.
```

Answer (score 0):

[DowntThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) might offer that functionality.